# Stop interface name iteration?

Tags: tty, udev

I have a device that comes up as `ttyACM0`, however every time it is reset it iterates, so next time it will come up as `ttyACM1` etc. Where might this `lock` be located so that I can remove it? 

I'd like the device to come up as `ttyACM0` repeatedly and only a second device show as `ttyACM1`.

Comment: When this happens, is there still a `/dev/ttyACM0` device? And if so, does some process have it open? (use `lsof` to find out).

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick There is always a device as the system is using a static device table, I have added multiple ACM interfaces to it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do exactly what you want -- force the device to register as `ttyACM0` -- however, you can set up a [udev rule to create a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-there-a-way-to-change-device-names-in-dev-directory), associated with a specific device, so that regardless of whether it registers as `ttyACM0` or `ttyACM1`, the specified symlink (e.g., `/dev/my_ttyACM`) will be available to access it.

The reason you can't force `ttyACM0` instead of `ttyACM1` is that this is selected by the kernel and cannot/should not be renamed.

Comment: Hi, I 'll try that out cheers, sounds good! As I am using a static device table I just have to see how often the device resets, because if this happens hundreds of times it will be a nightmare to add all those to a static device table? Anyway will have a look thank you!