# How can the link target of /dev/rtc be changed?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, embedded

On my Beaglebone Black I [added a I2C real-time-clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549211/how-to-add-i2c-devices-on-the-beaglebone-black-using-device-tree-overlays) to not being reliant on ntpd to maintain accurate timing. The outcome is that there are two special device files in `/dev`. These are `/dev/rtc0` and `/dev/rtc1` but there is also `/dev/rtc` which is a symlink to `/dev/rtc0`.

[image]

`/dev/rtc0` is the real-time-clock within the ARM SOC on the board, `/dev/rtc1` is the I2C device. At the moment I'm using scripts that read and write the time manually to the I2C clock but I'd rather like the symlink `/dev/rtc` to point to `/dev/rtc1`.

Hence the question, how can this be done? The Linux distro on my beaglebone black is Arch Linux which uses systemd for all the house keeping.

When I delete the symlink and create a new one pointing to `/dev/rtc1` not surprisingly it is reset after the next reboot and I didn't find any config files or systemd-units so far.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You would need udev rules. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-there-a-way-to-change-device-names-in-dev-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That udev rule hint pointed me in the right direction. After a quick review of [writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) I did the following.

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/rtc/rtc1
```

The output (shortened) revealed some useful properties to define a udev rule.

```
looking at device '/devices/platform/ocp/4802a000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0068/rtc/rtc1':
KERNEL=="rtc1"
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{date}=="2015-12-04"
ATTR{hctosys}=="0"
ATTR{max_user_freq}=="64"
ATTR{name}=="ds1307"
ATTR{since_epoch}=="1449230817"
ATTR{time}=="12:06:57"
...
```

So the rules file needs to reside in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with a naming scheme like `99-rtc1.rules`.

The files content is

```
KERNEL=="rtc1", SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", DRIVER=="", ATTR{name}=="ds1307", SYMLINK="rtc", MODE="0666"
```

To test the rule you can run

```
udevadm test /sys/class/rtc/rtc1
```

and the important lines in the output are

```
...
creating link '/dev/rtc' to '/dev/rtc1'
atomically replace '/dev/rtc'
...
```

The result in `/dev` is the desired configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things to get my I2C RTC working on a Orange Pi PC plus with a builtin RTC, I've managed (a nasty way) to have it working.

1. Find out the path to the built-in rtc:

```
#>find /sys | egrep 'rtc$'
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/sun6i-rtc/1f00000.rtc
```

You'll probably get many lines, just focus on the ones with "/sys/bus..."

2. Create a udev to manage the creation of the device and device links

```
#>nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-rtc1.rules
```

Paste this content:

```
KERNEL=="rtc1", SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", DRIVER=="", ATTR{name}=="rtc-ds1307 0-0068", ATTR{hctosys}=="0", SYMLINK+="rtc", SYMLINK+="rtc0", MODE="0666"
```

3. Now, you have to create a systemd service:

```
#>nano /etc/systemd/system/rtc.service
```

The below content has to be edited according to your rtc0 built-in and rtc1 i2c devices on the line `ExecStart`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Initialize ds1307 RTC and sincronize system clock
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=systemd-modules-load.service
After=systemd-modules-load.service
#Before=sysvinit.target
ConditionPathExists=/sys/class/i2c-adapter
#Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo -n "1f00000.rtc" > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/sun6i-rtc/unbind && echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/new_device && hwclock --rtc /dev/rtc --hctosys --utc"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Enable the service:
   `#>systemctl enable rtc.service`
5. Start the service:
   `#>systemctl start rtc.service`
6. You may check if the `/dev/rtc*` devices have changed accordingly using `ls -lah /dev/rtc*` you should have something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Apr  3 18:19 /dev/rtc -> rtc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Apr  3 18:19 /dev/rtc0 -> rtc1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 253, 1 Apr  3 18:19 /dev/rtc1
```

Now rtc and rtc0 are pointing to rtc1!

7. Check if hwclock is working with `hwclock --verbose`

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.37.2
System Time: 1680548612.161304
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1680540088 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1680540088 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
ioctl(4, RTC_UIE_ON, 0): Invalid argument
Waiting in loop for time from /dev/rtc0 to change
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2023/04/03 19:03:33
Hw clock time : 2023/04/03 19:03:33 = 1680548613 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 8525 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
2023-04-03 19:03:32.766066+00:00
```

To update your clock with system time just use `hwclock -w` to update from rtc use `hwclock -s`

You must add your module to the /etc/modules
`echo "rtc-ds1307" >> /etc/modules`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).