# Rename USB Sound device

Tags: usb, audio, udev

I have raspberry pi running raspbian that has 3 sound devices plugged in via USB. I successfully renamed the card ids for alsa based on the USB port with this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9.2/1-9.2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="Audio_Channel_1"

LABEL="my_usb_audio_end"
```

(plase not that the USB path may be off, ive done this on my computer for now not on the raspberry).

What I would like to change now too is the device name reported by lsusb. Currently this is:

```
USB PnP Sound Device, USB Audio
```

How can I also rename the device name with udev?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change device names in /dev directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-there-a-way-to-change-device-names-in-dev-directory)

Comment: No its not. I dont want to rename devices in dev, i want to change the usb descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the output of `lsusb` with `udev`.

Actually, you can't change the output of `lsusb` at all, the names are reported by the USB devices themselves.

Answer (score 0):

While `lsusb` only shows the device name by vendor and model ID (on my system it is in `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/*usb*`) where you potentially could change device names, you actually changed ALSA's card ID.

You can check it with `aplay -L` or `/proc/asound/cards` and use it as a device name.

See https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Changing_card_IDs_with_udev