# Controlling the name of a USB device using udev rule

Tags: udev

I have a Prolific serial adapter. When I attach it, it gets the name `ttyUSB0`. I have created the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-serial.rules` with the following content

```
KERNELS=="1-2", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SYMLINK="prolific"
```

This is **working well**, and I can access `/dev/prolific`! (I know that I am overwriting other symbolic links by not using +=).

Now my question: is it possible to control the **'primary' name** of the device (`ttyUSB0`) like so:

```
KERNELS=="1-2", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", NAME="prolific"
```

I have not been able make this work.

Here is the relevant (?!) output of `udevadm info -a /dev/ttyUSB0`:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""    
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

Background: on a different machine, there are tons of test scripts which are using the device names `ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1`. Unfortunately, the two devices are getting swapped every now and then when rebooting the machine. People have taken the pain and un/replugged the devices in the right order after each reboot, which is no longer acceptable. I could now change all the scripts and use symbolic links as described above, or I could try to assign fixed names to the devices, which in my eyes would be the superior solution by far.

All the solutions I have found put additional names on top but do not touch the names assigned by the system.

Comment: You cannot change the kernel name. Just create symlinks, and modify your code to use those. You'll be better off if you can match on vendor/product codes rather than `KERNELS`.

Comment: You cannot change the name of a device /dev/tty*. @larsks makes a good point. Please, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120272/72707.